# Find sublist of strings that match a regex that requires ordered inclusion from another list

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a list `lst` with dozens of thousands of strings. Say also that I have a list of strings 
`strings_to_match`, e.g.:

```
strings_to_match = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello']
```

I would like to find strings within `lst` that include  all of the strings in `strings_to_match_against` **respecting the order**.

For example if `lst` is

```
[ 'foo-yes-bar', 'hello foo fine bar', 'abcdf foo,bar, hello?']
```

then `result` should be `'abcdf foo,bar, hello?'`, since that string holds all the strings within `strings_to_match`, and they appear in the same order.

I have something like the following:

```
result = [x for x in lst if re.search(my_pattern, x)]
```

But I don't know how to define `my_pattern` using `strings_to_match`

Comment: If `strings_to_match = ["abcd", "cdef"]` and `lst` contains `"abcdef"`, would you expect this string to match?

Comment: @SvenMarnach It should not match (i.e. `result` should be empty if `"abcdef"` is the only entry in `lst`)

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them" -- I only gave one entry for `lst`!  The point is whether overlapping matches should count.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I meant that `"abcdef"` does not match anything in `strings_to_match`, so that string would not make it to `result`

Comment: Well, `"abcdef"` contains both of the strings to match, though with overlap.  So the strings in `strings_to_match` are actually whole words, and you are only looking for whole-word matches, right?

Comment: @SvenMarnach. Yes. I also just updated the post to force respecting the order of the items in `strings_to_match`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Regex is necessary:

```
>>> lst = [ 'foo-yes-bar', 'hello foo fine bar']
>>> strings_to_match = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello']
>>> [x for x in lst if all(s in x for s in strings_to_match)]
['hello foo fine bar']
>>>
```

However, if you want to use Regex, I guess this would work:

```
[x for x in lst if all(re.search(s, x) for s in strings_to_match)]
```

**Edit:**

Oh, well, since you want to respect order, you can do this:

```
[x for x in lst if re.search(".*".join(map(re.escape, strings_to_match)), x)]
```

My post though was geared towards your original question.

Comment: Thanks. I would still be interested in a solution that builds `my_pattern` and uses `re.search` (I will probably build more complex examples starting from it)

Comment: Use `all(s in x for s in strings_to_match)` instead.

Comment: `str.count()` cannot short-circuit, while `sub in s` can.

Comment: @arshajii - Good call.

Comment: Thanks @iCodez. I apologize for the confusion. I have updated the post to force the method to only include matches if the string appear in the same order as specified in `strings_to_match`

Answer (score 2):

Answer for the updated question: You can use

```
my_pattern = ".*".join(map(re.escape, strings_to_match))
```

to match any string containing `strings_to_match` in the given order.

You can filter the list either using your list comprehension, or using `filter()`:

```
result = filter(re.compile(my_pattern).search, lst)
```

Using `filter()` is slightly more efficient in this particular case.